# AnimatedSwitcher does not animate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make a news section in my app. In this page that's gonna display the news, i want to be able to click anywhere on the page and get the news that is next in my list. So far no problem with that, but i wanted it to have a nice animation so i tried implementing AnimatedSwitcher, but i can't figure out why there is no animation showing.

I tried changing the hierarchy of my code. Putting the gesture detector inside the animated switcher and the other way around. Letting the main container outside or inside of it too. I tried an animation builder that would scale it just in case it wasnt obvious enough but nothing. Tried changing the duration too but that wasn't it.

```
class ShowNews extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowNewsState createState() => _ShowNewsState();
}

class _ShowNewsState extends State<ShowNews> {
  List<News> _news = [
    News(title: 'OYÉ OYÉ', desc: 'bla bla bla bla bla'),
    News(title: 'another one', desc: 'plus de bout d\'histoire'),
    News(title: 'boum', desc: 'attention à l\'accident'),
    News(title: 'Lorem ipsum', desc: 'Lorem ipsum in doloris'),
  ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (_currentIndex < _news.length - 1) {
            _currentIndex++;
          } else {
            _currentIndex = 0;
          }
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 160,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
          child: ColumnArticle(_news, _currentIndex),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine but the animation.

Edit: I tried adding a key to make it different but still no animation.

```
class ColumnArticle extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<News> _news;
  final int _currentIndex;

  ColumnArticle(this._news, this._currentIndex);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      key: ValueKey<int>(_currentIndex),
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          _news[_currentIndex].title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Text(
          _news[_currentIndex].desc,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it changes to the related news page at least, even without animation?

Comment: Yes it does but there's no animation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That happens because the `AnimatedSwitcher` will add an animation *anytime* it is rebuilt with a different child reference. However, in your widget lifecycle, you are always using a `ColumnArticle` as a child, thus, not actually swapping any widget type, that's where the `ValueKey` comes in play.

You can use the index as the reference for the key, but **make sure it actually changes**, otherwise it won't work and you also need to pass it to your `ColumnArticle` base widget (`super`).

So, your `ColumnArticle` should look like this:

```
class ColumnArticle extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<News> _news;
  final int _currentIndex;

  ColumnArticle(this._news, this._currentIndex) : super(key: ValueKey<int>(_currentIndex));

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Passing the same type of widget with different attributes will not trigger an animation since they are the same widgets for the framework. It's also mentioned in the [description](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html).

> If the "new" child is the same widget type and key as the "old" child,
> but with different parameters, then AnimatedSwitcher will not do a
> transition between them, since **as far as the framework is concerned,
> they are the same widget** and the existing widget can be updated with
> the new parameters. To force the transition to occur, set a Key on
> each child widget that you wish to be considered unique (typically a
> ValueKey on the widget data that distinguishes this child from the
> others).

Here is the code from `AnimatedSwitcher` that checks whether to animate or not:

```
if (hasNewChild != hasOldChild ||
      hasNewChild && !Widget.canUpdate(widget.child, _currentEntry.widgetChild)) {
    // Child has changed, fade current entry out and add new entry.
    _childNumber += 1;
    _addEntryForNewChild(animate: true);
}
```

This is the static `canUpdate` method from the framework:

```
static bool canUpdate(Widget oldWidget, Widget newWidget) {
  return oldWidget.runtimeType == newWidget.runtimeType
      && oldWidget.key == newWidget.key;
}
```

To solve this you can set individual keys to your `News` widgets based on their distinct attributes (eg. text, count, value). `ValueKey<T>` is just for that.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
     AnimatedSwitcher(
         duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    
         child: Text(
             '$_count',
             // This key causes the AnimatedSwitcher to interpret this as a "new"
             // child each time the count changes, so that it will begin its animation
             // when the count changes.
             key: ValueKey<int>(_count),
         ),
     ),
     RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('Increment'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _count += 1;
            });
          },
     ),
])
```

Comment: I tried this with my currentIndex that changes everytime i click, but still no animation.
( i have posted my widget in my question with the key )

Comment: Something that might help others.  I didn't realize the `key` property needed to be on the `Text` widget.  I had it on the same left as the child and duration which causes the animation not to work.